# Role of baseAddress while configurting WCF Service EndPoint

Tags: wcf, endpoint

I have created simple WCF service and configured its endpoint as bellow.

```
<services>
  <service name="AsynchWCFService.MathOperation">
    <endpoint address="MathsOperation" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AsynchWCFService.IMathOperation">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>            
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/OperationService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

I have hosted this WCF service in a stand alone exe.  I am expecting that my service will be accessible at below address.

```
http://localhost:8080/OperationService/MathsOperation/
```

But service is accessible at `http://localhost:8080/OperationService/`

I want to access service using `http://localhost:8080/OperationService/MathsOperation/` link.  Can any one help me?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the absolute path: `<endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/OperationService/MathsOperation/" ...`?

Comment: @rae1n Thanks.  I tried this and working properly.  But I just wnat to understand how relative addressing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your service is available at `http://localhost:8080/OperationService`. What you see there is just a HTML page created by WCF which describes available `mex` endpoints or path to WSDL.
These mex endpoints describe the ABC of your WCF service where A = address => `http://localhost:8080/OperationService/MathsOperation/`. Potential clients know about your service url by querying the mex endpoint.

By default, this HTML page will show up at your base address. However, you can disable this page or set it to appear at some different url by using `serviceDebug` behavior.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceDebug httpHelpPageUrl="http://localhost:8080/OperationService/myhelppage"
                               /> <!-- use httpHelpPageEnabled="false" to disable the page -->
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Unfortunately, I don't think you can set `httpHelpPageUrl` to same address as your service endpoint.

Comment: yes you are right.  I checked .config file of the client and its address is 'http://localhost:8080/OperationService/MathsOperation'  Thanks.